# How use filter eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables

- Calls: id, title, place_id...
- Places: id, name, departament_id...
- Departaments: id, name...

In models

```
class Call extends Model
{
    public function place(){
        return belongsTo('App\Place');
    }
}

class Place extends Model
{
    public function departament(){
        return belongsTo('App\Departament');
    }
}
```

and on the controller

```
$calls = new \App\Call;

if($status != ''){
    $calls = $calls::with(['places'=>function($q) use ($departament){
        $q->where('places.departament_id','=',$departament);
    }]);
}
```

I want filter calls from certain department, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please explain how it doesn't work. Provide an example of the current result and the expected result.

Comment: Shouldn't that be with place rather than places? Also, department is misspelled.

Comment: Text slightly improved.

Comment: @CindyMeister, see my code please: http://pastebin.com/w5vYZ8Rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues with your code.
I'm gonna give you the correct solution, and hopefully you'll read through what was changed and see where you went wrong, because honestly, it would be too much to explain everything wrong :P

```
class Call extends Model
{
    public function place(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Place::class);
    }
}

class Place extends Model
{
    public function departament(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Departament::class);
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
if($status != ''){
    $calls = Call::with('place')->where('departament_id', $departament)->get();
}
```

**Note: Department is mispelled**

Comment: Sorry Pistachio, I was wrong at the time to describe the error, signed the code with several mistakes here in the forum, however even using your tip has not worked.

Comment: I tried:
    $calls = \App\Call::with('place')->where('departament_id',$departament)->paginate(10);

Comment: Remember you need a `place_id` on your `calls` table and a `department_id` on your `places` table.

Comment: You need to use the `get()` method to actually fetch your results. `with('place')->where('departament_id',$departament)->get();`. Sorry, but you should go to codereview or even better - go check out laravel fundamentals@laracasts (https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals)